# python string formatting: way to not use two lists?

Tags: python

With the following code:

```
a = ['foo', 'bar', 'doh', 'rae']
```

I'd like the string `SUM(foo) AS foo, SUM(bar) AS bar, SUM(doh) AS doh, SUM(rae) AS rae`. This works:

Tried something clever like `'SUM(%s) AS %s' % ([x for x in a], [x for x in a])` but obviously it didn't work, and using two list comprehensions felt woefully inefficient.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the [str.format method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)?

```
", ".join(['SUM({n}) AS {n}'.format(n=x) for x in a])
# Returns SUM(foo) AS foo, SUM(bar) AS bar, SUM(doh) AS doh, SUM(rae) AS rae
```

If `a` is a large list, you may want to use a generator instead, in order to avoid creating the whole list in memory first, as GWW points out.

```
", ".join('SUM({n}) AS {n}'.format(n=x) for x in a)
```

Comment: Your code would be more efficient if you used a generator instead of the list comprehension.

Comment: While it might be less efficient, you could also do something along the lines of `', '.join('SUM('+x+') AS '+x for x in a)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a str.format function to deliver one argumet twice in a string, something like that:

```
s = ', '.join(['SUM({0}) AS {0}'.format(x) for x in a])
```

and with one list comprehension and a join operation it produces desired output

```
'SUM(foo) AS foo, SUM(bar) AS bar, SUM(doh) AS doh, SUM(rae) AS rae'
```

Greetings!